# cucumber with timecop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm trying to use cucumber and timecop together and it's timecop doesn't seem to be overriding my Time.now call in my transaction.rb model file.

Here is my Scenario:

```
  @stop @wip
  Scenario: Displaying defaults when entering a form
    Given I am on the new transaction page
    And the time is Dec 31 2010, 9:00 UTC
    Then the "Tran date" field should contain "31/12/2010"
```

I have these steps in a timecop_steps.rb file

```
Given 'the time is $time' do |time|
  Timecop.freeze Time.parse(time)
end

When '$time pass' do |time|
  Timecop.travel future_time(time)
  Given 'delayed jobs are run' # we use delayed jobs and have some that get scheduled in the future.
end

When 'time stands still' do
  Timecop.freeze Time.now
end
```

Then in my transaction.rb file I set my default:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_defaults
    self.tran_date = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end
end
```

When I run my scenario I get the following:

```
  Scenario: Displaying defaults when entering a form   # features/receipt_journal_new.feature:29
    Given I am on the new transaction page
                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:45
    And the time is Dec 31 2010, 9:00 UTC                              # features/step_definitions/timecop_steps.rb:1
    Then the "Tran date" field should contain "31/12/2010"             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:142
      expected: /31\/12\/2010/
           got: "20/07/2011" (using =~)
      Diff:
      @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
      -/31\/12\/2010/
      +20/07/2011
       (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:30:in `with_scope'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:143:in `/^the "([^"]*)" field(?: within (.*))? should contain "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/transaction_new.feature:32:in `Then the "Tran date" field should contain "31/12/2010"'
```

Update:

I've even tried stubbing out Time.now and that didn't work either:

```
Given 'the time is $time' do |time|
  Time.stub!(:now).and_return("31/12/2010") #Time.parse(time))
#  Timecop.freeze Time.parse(time)
end
```

Update2:

I've tried using chronic as well as using Timecop.travel instead of Timecop.freeze as in this article:

http://www.louismrose.me.uk/post/876230592/freezing-time-in-cucumber

Update3:

I've tested Timecop in my rspec model tests and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply the order in which I was setting Timecop in my Scenario

```
Given the time is Dec 31 2010, 9:00 UTC
And I am on the new transaction page
```